# Filter certain column with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I try to filter an array of objects using ng-repeat on a specific key or you might even call it column.
The key/column on which the filter should be applied on, comes from an selectbox.

```
data-ng-model="selectedValue" // -> item.name
```

The term which should be searched for comes from an input field and is decalred as following:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="q">

<div data-ng-repeat="item in items |filter:{selectBoxValue:q}">{{item.name}}</div>
```

The above does not work, sadly.
But when I use item.name instat of selectBoxValue in my filter, it works great.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle/plunker of this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your controller:** 
$scope.search = {}

**In your markup**

`<input ng-model="colName"> //colName
<input ng-model="search[colName]"> //colvalue`

`<div data-ng-repeat="item in items |filter:search">{{item.name}}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
Now you can filter on specific column, in case anyProperty.

```
<input type="button" ng-click="changeFilter('anyProperty')">
<input type="text" ng-model="q[filter]">
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:q">

$scope.changeFilter = function(q){
   $scope.filter = q;
}
```